# is it possible to commit a git exclude file?

Tags: git

How to commit a file in `.git/info/exclude` file to a Git repo?

So here is the deal:
I want to ignore all the css files locally but I don't want to add it to `.ignore` file because I compile them on my server, commit the css files and deploy it.

I know I can run

1. `git update-index --assume-unchanged`
2. Add it to `.git/info/exclude` file manually

There are almost 10 developers working and I don't want them to commit any css files to my Git repo, and, if one forgets to do the above tasks, the css files will be included.

Any other way of adding/commiting `.git/info/exclude` without any manual work?

Alternatively, I could do a bash script, but is there any easier way with Git?

Comment: So wait... do you want to compile the CSS files or not? That's not clear to me.

Comment: i compile scss to css on my server, but i don't want any css to be included in the repo while compiling.

Comment: But you need to commit the generated CSS in order to deploy them. Correct?

Comment: You're trying to commit builds to the same repo as source. The best thing to do is not do that. :)

Comment: Any other alternative way?

Comment: Generally, you avoid putting derived files (such as the output of compilers) into the version control system (VCS). You can rebuild the outputs at any time because you have the master versions of the source code in the VCS, and you have installation images for any of the software that is used in the compilation that you do not build from source.  So, you do not need the compiler output under version control. Well, that's the theory. In practice, some outputs are placed in version control, but you need to be consistent; whenever the sources change, you place the rebuilt outputs in the VCS too.

Comment: You could use two repositories: one repo (A) in which you stricly keep source files only (no CSS or other generated files allowed), and another repo (B) that you only use for deployment. You would do all development in A, commit (in repo A), then compile and copy (with a script) all files needed for deployment to the working tree of repo B, commit in repo B, and then push to deploy.